# Ubuntu 11.10: GCC/G++ won't link libraries

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, linker, g++, sdl

I went to compile a project of mine, which uses SDL, SDL_ttf, OpenAL, and GTK. All of which are outputting errors like the following:

```
TxtFunc.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
TxtFunc.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `TTF_RenderText_Solid'
TxtFunc.cpp:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `SDL_UpperBlit'
TxtFunc.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `TTF_CloseFont'
TxtFunc.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `SDL_FreeSurface'
```

for every library call. I am compiling with the following link options:

`sdl-config --libs` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config openal --libs` -lalut -lSDL_ttf

I have all of these packages installed, and there are no "file not found" errors. Just a lot of undefined references... It didn't make sense, so I wrote up a quick test application:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    return 0;
}
```

and compile like so:

```
g++ `sdl-config --libs --cflags` -o sdl-test ./sdl-test.cpp
```

I have even tried linking directly to "/usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0" or "/usr/lib/libSDL.a" instead

all of these options end up with the same output:

```
/tmp/cc05XT8U.o: In function `main':
sdl-test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally you need to have your -l options *after* the files that use the symbols on the command line. Perhaps try moving the `sdl-config --libs --cflags` to the end of the command? i.e. for your test program:

```
g++ -o sdl-test ./sdl-test.cpp `sdl-config --libs --cflags`
```

Comment: OP may want to also read this explanation of why the order of libraries on command line matters: http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I guess I never knew it mattered, and had just always happened to write it correctly! 

Employed Russian: Yeah that does make a lot of sense!

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2):

Gah, which pillock got the idea to change the compiler to rely now on the order of options in the command line?

Well,that fixed my problem too, just moved ($CFLAGS) after ($OBJS) in my Makefile and all my linking problems with unknown references to SDL libs are gone >.<

Answer (score 0):

In case you use SDL_ttf, you need to

```
g++ main.cpp -o sdl-test `sdl-config --libs --cflags` -lSDL_ttf
```