# Linking Against SDL From a C Program

Tags: c, sdl

I have a very simple C program that is [taken from the SDL documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usinginit.html):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm using `sdl-config --cflags --libs` to provide the arguments to clang.  It is able to link against the SDL headers, but fails to link against the SDL library:

```
/tmp/example-f2Tgg6.o: In function `main':
example.c:7: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
example.c:8: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried to compile with gcc and get the same problem, so I feel I've missed something obvious.  I'm running xubuntu 11.10 in case that's relevant.

Comment: It cannot find the libraries -> SDL.lib and sdlmain.lib

Comment: Where should I look for SDL.lib and sdlmain.lib?  Are those the Windows equivalents of `.a` files?  Because I'm fairly sure `ld` is finding the SDL library since if I change -lSDL to -lrubbish I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrubbish`.

Comment: Put your SDL.dlls in executable folder and SDL.libs to where you tell your IDE/compiler they should be.

Answer (score 0):

try to install libraries. something like `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl1.2debian`

Comment: I already have those.  And, like I said in my comment above, I'm fairly sure `ld` is finding the SDL library.

Comment: maybe this link could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498899/ubuntu-11-10-gcc-g-wont-link-libraries

Answer (score 0):

First, you can always figure out the correct flags using `pkg-config`, as shown [here](https://github.com/slezica/bleg/blob/master/data/posts/2013-02-12-figuring-out-compilation-flags.md).

Then you can use `apt-file` and Google to figure out which packages you need installed via `apt`. In this case, look in `libsdl-*` -- you may want the base package, and the `-dev` package.

Comment: The link to your `pkg-config` example is now broken. It would be helpful if you could include an example in the body of your answer. =]

Comment: Here's how you can compile SDL 2.0 on a Mac using pkg-config: `gcc example.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)`